# Why "保重" means "take care"?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary, etymology, phrase

As far as I have learnt, for each Chinese word with more than one character, its meaning is formed from that of each character which it comprises. However, I cannot understand how the meaning of `保重` is formed this way. I thought that:

- 保 = to protect
- 重 = important

what would `保` and `重` mean for this word? How does it go from "to protect the important one" to "take care"?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is true that this word originally comes from 《晋书·夏侯湛传》：“方将保重啬神，独善其身。”
But we use it in situation of farewell. 珍重 is heavier than 保重。 珍重包含了珍惜cherish.

保 是保住，保持，守 。 keep， reserve probably.

重 has two tones:

1. zhòng 是分量较大，与“轻”相反。 large amount or heavy. opposite with light. 很重，举重。
2. chóng means again. doubled. 重复，重播。

In the phrase 保重 is zhòng. In my appoint: strong power. strength.

Does it make sense? ([Reference](http://xh.5156edu.com/html5/z39m31j146490.html).)

Answer (score 1):

It is an ancient word for modern use.In ancient word "保重" came from "保重啬神" in Taoism and means "Keep healty".It become a popular word but nobody care the original reference in Chinese.